# application to find number of pixels between two points in an image

Tags: image, pixel

I am building an app that can measure number of pixels between two points in it. One should able to take a photo through it and then get the number of pixels between the manually added two points.

I am a beginner and i don't know where to start and which platform to use. And what should i do to calculate number of pixels. Can anyone help me with stepwise guide.

Comment: It really really depends on what the app is; Is it a browser based (js) app, a desktop app, iOS etc? I suggest a simple bit of JS will do the trick. That said, in a nutshell you just need to load in the image with some image library (or simple js), note it's dimensions (width and height). Allow and record your two click positions. Work out distance in pixels between (remember line may not be horizontal). Last it of info to look for then is the DPI and PPI.

Comment: It is a android app for smartphones. So can i do this complete project in android studio?! Or should i use any other workspace?